# Why is a pseudo-abelian category idempotent complete?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, universal-property

A category is pseudo-abelian if it is pre-additive and idempotents have images. For my purpose, I only care about additive pseudo-abelian categories, which makes things slightly easier.

I want to show that an idempotent $p : X \to X$ in a pseudo-abelian category splits. Let $(K, k : K \to X)$ be the image of $p$. By the universal property of kernels, there exists a map $r : X \to K$ such that $p = kr$. nLab [says](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Karoubian+category#general) that $rk = 1_K$, but I can't prove this.

I have tried to prove this using the uniqueness of the map in the universal property, but this hasn't worked.

Using $p^2 = p$, we get $k(rk) r = kr$. If monics had left inverses and epics right inverse in a pseudo-abelian category (is this true and why?), then we would have $rk = 1_K$.

Comment: Use that $k$ is a mono and $r$ is an epi and $krkr = pp=p= kr=k1_Kr$. i.e $krkr =k1_Kr \Rightarrow rkr = 1_Kr$ (because $k$ is mono) and then $ rkr = 1_Kr \Rightarrow rk=1_K$ (because $r$ is epi).

Comment: Yes, of course! This should be an answer.

Comment: By the way, this is nothing special to abelian categories. If an idempotent in any category admits an equalizer with the identity morphism, then that gives a splitting of the idempotent. The only extra thing to show is that the analogue of $r$ is guaranteed to be epi, without assuming it came from an image factorization.

Comment: Why do you know $r$ is epi? Wikpedia -
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(category_theory)#General_Definition - says that if C has all equalisers then $r$ is epi. But a pseudo-abelian category might not have all equalisers, and I can't see how to generalise the proof.

Comment: Here is another way that doesn't use that $r$ is epimorphism. I assume that $k$ is the kernel of $1_X-p$. Note that this means that $0=(1_X-p)k=k-pk$ and hence $k=pk$. Now we have that $krk=pk=k$ and so since $k$ is mono $rk=1_K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer given by Nex in the comments. First a bit of background:

**Definition:**
In a category $\mathscr C$, an idempotent $p : X \to X$ *splits* if there are morphisms $r : X \to Y$ and $s : Y \to X$ such that $s \circ r = e$ and $r \circ s = 1_Y$. A category $\mathscr C$ is *idempotent complete* if every non-zero idempotent splits.

Note that the condition $r \circ s = 1_Y$ implies that $r$ is epic and $s$ monic.

**Definition:**
A category $\mathscr C$ is *pseudo-abelian* if it is additive and every idempotent has an image.

Some authors only require a pseudo-abelian category to be pre-additive.

Every idempotent $p : X \to X$ in an additive category (or a pre-additive category with a terminal object) $\mathscr C$ has a cokernel $(X, 1_X - p)$. The proof of this is straightforward Since $1_X - p$ is also an idempotent if and only if $p$ is an idempotent, an additive category is pseudo-abelian if and only if every idempotent has a kernel.

**Proposition:**
A pseudo-abelian category is idempotent complete.

Proof:
Let $p : X \to X$ be an idempotent with image $(K, k : K \to X)$. We know $k$ is the kernel of $1_X - p$. This implies $0 = (1_X-p)k$ and consequently $k = pk$. By the universal property of kernels, there exists a map $r : X \to K$ such that $p = kr$. Thus, $krk = pk = k$ and so $rk = 1_K$ since $k$ is monic.